# Percentage Tier Pricing for Configurable Products

Tags: configuration, tierprice

I'm setting up a store to sell photographs that the user uploads.  They click on the product page and select a size (price increases as the size does) and a paper type.  I would like to add tier pricing so that if the user orders 10 they would get 10% off etc. but can't find a way that Magento will discount a percentage from each of the print size options.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this would be either using the catalog price rules, or shopping cart price rules. Information about using these can be found at: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/what-are-catalog-price-rules-and-how-do-i-use-them